# How to get C# Cmdlet Alias to show up in `Get-Help`

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I've decorated my cmdlet class inherited from PSCmdlet. Set up `[Alias("invexecsql")]`  attribute.
I see this alias in the result list from Get-Alias and my commandlet is working with this alias.
Also I'd like see the alias after executing `Get-Help [mycomdlet] -Full`. I don't see it. 
What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Help` doesn't show the alias. `Get-Help` is mostly based off of your [Comment-based Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-6), but does dynamically read the parameters and handle groupings for named parameter sets. If you want an alias to be shown in the documentation, I would recommend adding the alias to the `.PARAMETER` description for that parameter. You can also provide the alias in one of your `.EXAMPLE` fields.

If you think this would be a good enhancement for PowerShell, you are always free to submit a [Feature Request](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Issue-Enhancement&template=Feature_Request.md&title=Feature%20Request) on the [PowerShell Github repository](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell).